# Unexpected program fault-2

Tags: python, list

I have a list of stock tickers. The info is taken from yahoo finance.
My Python code calculates the daily percentage earn/loss of each of the 
tickers and shows the highest five tickers.

The problems i face:

1. When a ticker daily percentage ends with 0%,
2. When Yahoo presents a blank (black) chart.

In both casses the program terminates printing via try/except: "Error, one of the tickers is 0%".

Is it possible to terminate the program or bypass the error and print the ticker name who caused the error?

Thanks a lot,

Daniel

Here is the code:

!pip install ffn

```
import ffn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import traceback
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
#from scipy.stats import norm
%matplotlib inline

start = time.perf_counter()
tickers =  ['A','AA','AACG','AAL','AAME','AAN','AAON','AAP','AAPL','AAT','AAWW','AAXN','AB','ABBV','ABC','ABCB','ABEV','ABG','ABEO','ABIO',]

try:
    df = ffn.get(tickers, start='04/30/2020',end='12/31/2020').to_returns().dropna()
    #ticker_error = tickers.pop()
    #print(ticker_error)
    sums = df.select_dtypes(pd.np.number).sum() 
    sort_sums = sums.sort_values(ascending = False)
    print(df.shape)
    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start,2)}second(s)')
    print('---------------')
    print('% RETURN')
    print('---------------')
    print(sort_sums.as_format('.2%').head(40))
except:
    ticker_error = tickers.pop()   
    print(ticker_error)
    print('One of the tickers is ZERO %')
    pass
```

Comment: use `while` loop to keep working on same code, and in varible keep current processing stock and after except statement print that name ot identify that

Comment: Can you help further?

Comment: "...and in varible keep current processing stock and after except statement print that name ot identify that ".

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: can you show me your answer on my code?

Comment: hey sorry for late reply, instead of directly passing the ticketer list you can pass the indivitual ticketer [sample code using for loop to pass each tickter](https://ideone.com/BgmVkW)